# How to remove "<" special character between div and table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As shown in the screenshot below, I want to remove unwanted `<` special characters.

**NOTE: THIS IS NOT AN HTML ISSUE**

I am trying get child nodes via method below but don't know how to remove them.

**HTML**

```
<div>
>
>
>
>
>
<table>
</table>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('div')
        .contents()
        .filter(function(){
            return this.nodeType === 3 && /\S/.test(this.nodeValue);
        });
```

[image]

Comment: can you share your html code?

Comment: I have added html but this not an html issue. Something was breaking on server side so I need to apply some urgent fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure the code/HTML you're dealing with, but I would do something like this:

`$('div').text().replace(/</g, '');`

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0nnmr6vr/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out one way to fix this issue to set value `this.nodeValue`

```
$("div").contents()
    .filter(function(){
        this.nodeValue = '';
    });
```

Other solutions are welcomed.